# bootstrap modal not properly popped out

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a modal on ruby on rails. I set a **view** button so whenever it clicked, the modal will pop out. But it didn't worked properly. As you can see on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC5MK.png) the modal shouldn't be darken. Because of this, I cannot click anything on it. Here's my code:

**index.html.erb**

```
            <tbody>
              <% @quotations.each do |quotation| %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= quotation.customer.name %></td>
                  <td><%= quotation.build_quotation_number %></td>
                  <td><%= quotation.reference_no %></td>
                  <td align="center"><%= quotation.customer.tin %> . 
 </td>
                  <td align="center">
                    <% if current_administrator.admin? || quotation.created_by_id == current_administrator.id %>
                      <%= link_to ('<i class="ti-pencil-alt"> </i>').html_safe, edit_quotation_path(quotation), class: "btn btn-icon btn-fill btn-github", title: "Edit Quotation " + quotation.build_quotation_number, 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'top' %>
                    <% end %>

                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-fill btn-linkedin" title="View Quotation" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_quotation_modal"><i class="ti-eye"> </i></button>

                    <% if current_administrator.admin? || quotation.created_by_id == current_administrator.id %>
                      <%= link_to ('<i class="ti-trash"> </i>').html_safe, quotation_path(quotation), data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this quotation?'}, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-icon btn-fill btn-danger", title: "Delete Quotation " + quotation.build_quotation_number, 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'top' %>

                      +
                    <% end %>
                     <%= render partial: 'quotations/modal/view_quotation_modal', locals: { quotation: @quotation } %>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>

            </tbody>
```

_view_quotation_modal.html.erb

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="view_quotation_modal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Quotation</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <b>Customer</b>

  </div>  
     <div class="modal-footer">  
      <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <span style="padding-left: 460px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></span>
      </div>
     </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way. as you can see you are loading partial of modal in loop so there will n number of partials will be there for view_quotation_modal.

The bootstrap modal should always modal outside of the rest of your code, to the very bottom.

Add this below div in your main layout file like in application.html.erb

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static"></div>
```

You can do it in better as shown below, add separate action which will show modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-fill btn-linkedin" title="View Quotation" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_quotation_modal"><i class="ti-eye"> </i></button>
```

On click of above button, you can make ajax call to rails controller, or you simply use link_to instead of button which will call action of rails controller with passing needed parameters.

in rails controller.

```
def show_quotation
  # do your logic 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js 
   end
end
```

show_quotation.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'view_quotation_modal') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal();
```

You can access all instance variables in partial.